# python regular expression top 10

Tags: python, regex, list, dictionary

```
html_log:jeff 1153.3 1.84 625:54 1 2 71 3 2 10 7:58 499 3 5 616:36 241 36           
html_log:fred 28.7 1.04 27:34 -10 18 13 0:48 37 18 8 -3.63 
html_log:bob 1217.1 1.75 696:48 1 5 38 6 109 61 14:42 633 223 25 435:36 182 34 
... continues
```

above is the text file.

```
mystats = fo.readlines()
fo.close()

change = str(mystats)

pattern = re.compile("html_log:(?P<name>[^ ]*) (?P<score>[^ ]*)")
mylist=sorted(pattern.findall(change), key=lambda x: float(x[1]), reverse=True)
```

my output is now

```
bob 1217.1
jeff 1153.3
fred 28.7
```

Question..
I am trying to get the 5th int value however and my output should be

```
bob 5
jeff 2
fred 18
```

I don't know the pattern to match only the 5th value.

Comment: I don't see where the "top 10" is related to your question? Are you after the 5th element from the input (as your example shows), or the 5th after sorting?

Answer (score 2):

you don't really need regular expression for that.

```
s = [line.split() for line in file]
[(x[0].split(':')[1], float(x[5])) for x in s]
```

Comment: Where is the name of the person `bob` or `jeff`.

Answer (score 1):

How about this regex:

```
html_log:(?P<name>[^ ]*)(?: [^\s]+){4} (?P<score>[^ ]*)
```

See [here](http://regex101.com/r/rQ6uF4) for a test.

Answer (score 0):

A bit more traditional but survives short or empty lines:

```
import io # Python 3 use StringIO in Python 2
fobj = io.StringIO("""
html_log:jeff 1153.3 1.84 625:54 1 2 71 3 2 10 7:58 499 3 5 616:36 241 36           
html_log:fred 28.7 1.04 27:34 -10 18 13 0:48 37 18 8 -3.63 
html_log:bob 1217.1 1.75 696:48 1 5 38 6 109 61 14:42 633 223 25 435:36 182 34""")

scores = []
for line in fobj:
    split_line = line.split()
    try:
        scores.append((int(split_line[5]), split_line[0].split(':')[1]))
    except IndexError:
        continue
```

We need to sort them. Bigger is better:

```
top_ten = sorted(scores, reverse=True)[:10]
```

And display them a bit nicer:

```
for score, name in top_ten:
    print(name, score)
```

Output:

```
fred 18
bob 5
jeff 2
```

Comment: equivalent to a simple `if` in the list comprehension.

Comment: I guess you mean `if len(line.split()) > 5` . This would make for another split of the line. And there is the also the name the OP was looking for. Not sure how to get the name too with list comprehension without splitting the line once again for a total of three splits. And the name needs to be separated from the `html_log:` when read line by line from a file.

Answer (score 0):

Use this pattern:

```
pattern = re.compile(r'html_log:([^ ]*) (?:[^ ]+ ){4}([^ ]*)')
```

It skips 4 numbers and captures the fifth.